# Kohana 3.2 routing rewrite action

Tags: routes, kohana, url-rewriting

I have a uri scheme which is like `<country>/<id>_<action>/<name>` which descends from an old site and I am porting the site to the Kohana framewerk. A possible URL is `http://www.example.com/us/1234_1/foo`

The value of `<action>` is a digit from 0 to 9: `\d`. Every digit refers to a action, e.g. `0`  is `overview`.

How can I set my routing in the bootstrap, with the requested action ported correctly.

This is what I have now, but obviously it does not behave correctly, because it tries to call the function `Action_0` instead of `Action_Overview`, given the example url:

```
Route::set('default'), '<country>/<id>_<action>/<name>')
     ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action'     => 'index'
     ));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to name the actions action_0 to action_9, but I either of us likes that.

Another solution would be to 'reroute' the action in Controller::before() like this:

```
public function before()
{
    parent::before();

    $actions = array(0 => 'overview', ...);

    $this->request->action($actions[$this->request->action()]);
}
```

Or you could do that in a lambda/callback route, but I would keep it in Controller::before().

Answer (score 0):

It would of course be nice with a clean solution, but I'm afraid there isn't one available. I can think of a few ways to handle it, none of them, however, ideal.

**No 1.** Would be the subrouter idea provided by Darsstar

**No 2.** Would be similar to solution no. 1, but use a dual route system, along the lines of:

```
Route::set('default'), '<country>/<id>/<action>/<name>', array ('country' => '.+', 'name' => '.+', )) /* new */
 ->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'new',
    'action'     => 'index'
 ));
```

and

```
Route::set('legacy'), '<country>/<id>_<oldaction>/<name>', array ('country' => '.+', 'name' => '.+', 'oldaction' => '\d+', )) /* legacy */
 ->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'legacy',
    'action'     => 'route'
 ));
```

The new controller would use `action_overview()` etc. to your liking and the legacy would hold only one action, `action_route()` doing something like this:

```
public function action_route ()
{
  $actions = array (0 => 'overview', ...);

  $params = array (
    'country' => $this->request->param ('country'),
    'id' => $this->request->param ('id'),
    'action' => $actions[$this->request->param ('oldaction')],
    'name' => $this->request->param ('name'),
  );
  $this->request->redirect (Route::get ('legacy')->uri ($params));
}
```

**No 3.** Would be to simply use multiple routes, if the number of actions aren't that great, consider using one route per action like this:

```
Route::set('overview'), '<country>/<id>_0/<name>')
 ->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'index',
    'action'     => 'overview'
 ));

Route::set('details'), '<country>/<id>_1/<name>')
 ->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'index',
    'action'     => 'details'
 ));
```

You could make this a bit more manageable by using a `foreach()` along the lines of this:

```
$actions = array (
  'overview',
  'details',
);
foreach ($actions as $idx => $action)
{
  Route::set($action), '<country>/<id>_' . $idx . '/<name>')
    ->defaults(array(
      'controller' => 'index',
      'action'     => $action,
   ));
}
```

When this is done, you can use a controller with action `action_overview()`. In production, use caching for the routes to avoid redefining them on each request.

Personally I would opt for no 3 if it's a straight port and there's no plans for extending the site with new functionality. Otherwise I'd go with no 2, because it allows for a legacy mode that can be phased out over time. Also, it allows for more flexible "new" routes.
I would not choose no 1 only because it's -- in my mind -- not in keeping with the Kohana style of coding, I would personally expect to find routing rules either in *bootstrap.php* or *init.php* (in the case of modules). It's a perfectly valid solution otherwise (and in a sense it is in the style of Kohana, in that Kohana is flexible enough to allow for solutions that goes against it's general style... :) )